How can I handle floating-point precision in C when dealing with numbers very close to zero or other edge cases
I wrote a program in C that calculates three points based on three points that are given. So we are given points A, B, C and calculate points A', B', C'. Now there are three ways that these points form a shape on a 2D plane (ABA'C, ABCB' a AC'BC). Next, the program determines what type of shape was formed with these points either (square, rhombus, rectangle) or if none of those just output parallelogram. Here's an example when running the program:
Point A:
[0,0]
Point B:
[-3,4]
Point C:
[4,3]
A': [1,7], square
B': [7,-1], parallelogram
C': [-7,1], parallelogram

Here's an image for better understanding:

Now, the program works well for most cases. But given an edge case with numbers close to zero or big numbers. Such as:
Point A:
[78890.469e-63,0.669e-63]
Point B:
[2876.019e-63,78838.689e-63]
Point C:
[0.008e-63,0.669e-63]


My program outputs this:
Point A:
Point B:
Point C:
A': [-7.601444e-59,7.883869e-59], parallelogram
B': [7.601446e-59,-7.883735e-59], parallelogram
C': [8.176648e-59,7.883869e-59], square

//But it should output

Point A:
Point B:
Point C:
A': [-7.6014442e-59,7.8838689e-59], parallelogram
B': [7.6014458e-59,-7.8837351e-59], parallelogram
C': [8.176648e-59,7.8838689e-59], rhombus

Here is the whole program in C:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

// Struct for Point
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;

// Struct for Vector
typedef struct {
    double u1;
    double u2;
} Vector;

// Function to compute area
double area(Vector v) {
    return sqrt((v.u1 * v.u1) + (v.u2 * v.u2));
}

// Function to check for a right angle
double rightAngle(Vector u, Vector v) {
    if (fabs((u.u1 * v.u1) + (u.u2 * v.u2)) < 100 * DBL_EPSILON * fabs(u.u1 * v.u1) + 0.000000001) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Function to read a coordinate
int readCoord(const char* prompt, Point* p) {
    char z1, z2, z3;
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if (scanf(" %c %lf %c %lf %c", &z1, &p->x, &z2, &p->y, &z3) != 5 || z1 != 91 || z2 != 44 || z3 != 93) {
        printf("Incorrect input.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Function to check if three points are parallel
int areTheyParallel(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    if ((a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y) || (b.x == c.x && b.y == c.y) || (a.x == c.x && a.y == c.y)) {
        printf("Cannot create shapes.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    double s1 = (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
    double s2 = (c.y - b.y) / (c.x - b.x);

    if (fabs(s1 - s2) < 100 * DBL_EPSILON * s2) {
        printf("Cannot create shapes.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Function to determine and print the type of quadrilateral
void determineType(const char* point, Vector u, Vector v, Point p) {
    double size_u = area(u);
    double size_v = area(v);
    double isRightAngle = rightAngle(u, v);

    if (fabs(size_u - size_v) <= 100 * DBL_EPSILON * size_v && isRightAngle == 1) {

        printf("%s: [%.13g,%.13g], square\n", point, p.x, p.y);

    } else if (fabs(size_u - size_v) <= 100 * DBL_EPSILON * size_v && isRightAngle == 0) {

        printf("%s: [%.13g,%.13g], rhombus\n", point, p.x, p.y);

    } else if (fabs(size_u - size_v) >= 100 * DBL_EPSILON * size_v && isRightAngle == 1) {

        printf("%s: [%.13g,%.13g], rectangle\n", point, p.x, p.y);

    } else if (fabs(size_u - size_v) >= 100 * DBL_EPSILON * size_v && isRightAngle == 0) {

        printf("%s: [%.13g,%.13g], parallelogram\n", point, p.x, p.y);
    }
}

Point computeNewPoint(Point base, Vector translation) {
    Point newPoint;
    newPoint.x = base.x + translation.u1;
    newPoint.y = base.y + translation.u2;
    return newPoint;
}

Vector computeVector(Point from, Point to) {
    Vector v;
    v.u1 = to.x - from.x;
    v.u2 = to.y - from.y;
    return v;
}

int main() {
    Point A, B, C, newA, newB, newC;
    Vector u, v;

    if (!readCoord("Point A:\n", &A)) return 1;
    if (!readCoord("Point B:\n", &B)) return 1;
    if (!readCoord("Point C:\n", &C)) return 1;

    if (areTheyParallel(A, B, C)) return 1;

    // A'
    u = computeVector(A, C);
    newA = computeNewPoint(B, u);

    u = computeVector(A, B);
    v = computeVector(A, C);
    determineType("A'", u, v, newA);

    // B'
    u = computeVector(B, A);
    newB = computeNewPoint(C, u);

    u = computeVector(C, B);
    v = computeVector(A, B);
    determineType("B'", u, v, newB);

    // C'
    u = computeVector(C, A);
    newC = computeNewPoint(B, u);

    u = computeVector(A, C);
    v = computeVector(B, C);
    determineType("C'", u, v, newC);

    return 0;
}

What should I try to ensure it will work with these extreme edge cases where there are very small numbers or very big numbers?
To handle the edge case with floating-point precision in my program, I tried the following:
I defined a small tolerance value (epsilon) to compare floating-point numbers instead of checking for exact equality. For instance, I set epsilon to 1e-10, allowing the program to account for minor inaccuracies in calculations. But still I got the wrong output.
What should I try to implement. Could you guide me in the right direction. Help will be much appreciated.

In function determineType() you use an epsilon to test each shape in a fixed order, ending at the first 'match'. I suggest you stop using an epsilon, and compute the error there would be in the case of every shape, and pick the one with least error.

@WeatherVane sounds interesting. Thank you I am going to try that.

There are many different ways to (try to) test for "close enough" floating-point equality, and there are many Q/A pairs here on Stack Overflow about it.  But using 100 * DBL_EPSILON as your threshold is not a good way.  DBL_EPSILON gives you the "graininess" of double values near 1.0.  Due to the way floating-point representations work, 100 * DBL_EPSILON would give you the graininess of values near 100.  But if you're playing with values like 78890.469e-63, you would want to consider using a threshold more like 10000e-63 * DBL_EPSILON.

Some links: 1, 2,  3,  4,  5.

@SteveSummit Yes I have tried moving the threshold down but then it becomes inaccurate for values that are not crazy small like:
A: [740.865, 887.560]
B: [340.090, 1241.872]
C: [1095.177, 1288.335]

The accumulated rounding errors in a sequence of calculations are not necessarily limited by the magnitude of the final result or by an absolute value. Consider (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x). When the values were read, there were rounding errors converting the decimal input to double. These errors are generally around a fraction of DBL_EPSILON relative to the value. Then, if b.y and a.y are near each other, b.y - a.y is small relative to b.y, so an error that around DBL_EPSILON relative to b.y may be much larger relative to b.y - a.y…

… The amount of this error is not bounded by either the relative 100 * DBL_EPSILON * s2 or by an absolute 0.000000001. Figuring out what errors can occur and what errors you want to tolerate or what you want to do about them requires analysis of the calculations and some decisions about what inputs you want to support. (I do not have time for that at the moment. Maybe somebody else does.) Keep in mind that deciding to accept large errors that might occur means accepting as equal other numbers that are not actually equal, so it can lead to wrong decisions in the other direction.

@Jakubito My point was not to change 100 * DBL_EPSILON to 10 * DBL_EPSILON or anything like that.  I was thinking more along the lines of u.u1 * DBL_EPSILON, so that the comparison threshold automatically adjusts based on the magnitude of the numbers you're working with today.  (But as Eric P. points out in his comments, it's not that simple, either.)

Thanks for the comments. But I cannot solve this at the moment and really don't now what to try.

What are you really trying to solve? Is this an assignment for class? Is it for some interactive geometry graphics program? Is it for analysis of images? There are not many real-world problems that require working with units 63 orders of magnitude apart. Maybe none. So maybe for your actual problem, you do not need this code to work for tiny numbers. Explain the actual problem behind this, and maybe there is another route to a solution.

It is a problem that is tested on a site similar to leetcode and tested on a lot of data including these crazy edge cases and I have been trying to solve it and most tests are valid and the program runs correctly for them but there are these 3 edge cases including the one I shared above that keeps failing and I can't figure out why. So that's why I asked this question trying to get some help and learn something new :-)

I doubt this comment will be useful to you, but: most of us here consider leetcode and similar sites to be useless.  I don't mean any disrespect here, but if you're a beginner, trying to learn programming from one of those sites is like learning pole-vaulting by going to Paris last summer and sneaking into the Olympics, or learning how to drive by entering a demolition derby.

The problems on leetcode and similar sites are not easy, and they're often ill-advised.  Even if you get a program to "work", it's not clear if you'll have learned anything about how to program well.

Yes that's true I am not a fan of solving problems on leetcode or other sites I like writing apps that do something cool a lot more. I am also not a beginner I have been coding in JavaScript for a while but now I am trying to code a lot more often in C and other languages like C++ or Java and solving this problem in C I had to think about a lot more stuff because its a lower level programming language and It is something new having to take care of comparing doubles or pointers and so on. So that's why I asked this question.

Quite often the problems on those sites need to be solved by thinking out of the box, as well as writing effective code. But they aren't good places to learn coding, any more than solving crosswords is a good way to learn English.

@Jakubito My last two comments were probably a little harsh, and I was just about to delete them when you replied.  Setting aside my distaste for leetcode-like sites, if you can figure out what's going wrong for the "crazy edge cases", you probably will learn something useful about floating-point programming.  It's not too hard to write decent floating-point code that works well for "ordinary" cases, but the edge cases can be much harder.  Do chase those five links I gave earlier.


there are three ways that these points form a shape on a 2D plane


What should I try to implement.

Code might get by with floating-point math and types.  Yet floating point has a logarithmic distribution and OP's geometry really needs a linear (2D) distribution.
Fixed point
Consider instead a careful use of fixed point math (e.g. scaled integers) to solve this task.
Survey the FP points in question and form a scale.  I recommend a power-of-2 scale to prevent much inaccuracy.  Then round (via llround(x * scale)) to about 32-bit values and saved in an int64_t or long long.  The various is_a_certain_gemotric_shape() tests then proceed with internal integer math.
Area is interesting with its potential involvement of sqrt().  Many of the  area tests could be replaced with an area_squared test, negating the need for sqrt().
The effective epsilon here will be in the scale's units.

Scale example:
Illustrative idea (may need some adjustment, but to give an idea):
With [78890.469e-63,0.669e-63], [2876.019e-63,78838.689e-63], [0.008e-63,0.669e-63] the largest magnitude is 78890.469e-63.
double max = 78890.469e-63;
int power2;
frexp(max, &power2);
double scale = ldexp(1.0, 32 - power2);
long long a_x = llround(scale * 78890.469e-63);
long long a_y = llround(scale * 0.669e-63);
...

